# javascript losing decimals during assignment

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to do a simple thing but for some reason it is not working. I am using Knockout and I have a model which I update after user enter some data and use the same to communicate back to C# code on server side. For some reason, when I try to assign decimal value to one of the member of model it isn't working. Though, in this case I am using knockout, I believe it has nothing to do with KO. See the screenshot where I have the value 22.78 and I am trying to do parseFloat but it ends up as just 22. I tried other things such as removing he parseFloat just to see if it accepts the string value as it is but even that is not working. Can someone help?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Isn't that screenshot enough? It is just an assignment.

Comment: @Maverick `parseFloat` will not trim the decimals tough your screenshot says different .

Comment: @supercool I agree. parseFloat shouldn't trim and it will not, but something else is making the decimals to trim and that's what I am unable to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Your doing Bitwise OR while assigning the value.

```
this.AMOUNT_RECEIVED = parseFloat(data.AMOUNT_RECEIVED) | 0;
```

so only it returns 22. Because 22.78 | 0 is 22.
Please check this code.

```
console.log(22.78 | 0);
```

Please try this code while assigning value. You can get decimal values without loss.

```
this.AMOUNT_RECEIVED = parseFloat(data.AMOUNT_RECEIVED);
```

Pelase Check below link for more details.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR

Answer (score 2):

try this (please notice the double || )

this.AMOUNT_RECEIVED = parseFloat(data.AMOUNT_RECEIVED) || 0;

Comment: That indeed worked, it was a silly miss. I was only focusing on parseFloat and other things and never realized that I missed the extra pipe and that was leading to bitwise OR. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries. It is very easy to make syntax errors in Javascript :)